# nullpointerexception error in java gui

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am a new CS student learning java. I am trying to make a gui where user will enter a number and it will display the result. But i am getting some errors i am not familiar with. I have tried searching in google but it didnt help. Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Main Method with person class**

```
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class person {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame= new guifirst();//line 6
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

**GuiFirst class**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class guifirst extends JFrame{
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JTextField text;
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;

    public guifirst(){
        label=new JLabel("Enter a number");
        setSize(450,100);
        text=new JTextField(15);
        button=new JButton("Calculate");

        class addaction implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                double number=Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
                double result=number*number;
                label1=new JLabel("Your result is"+result);
            }
        }

        ActionListener listener=new addaction();
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(label1);//line 32
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(button);
        add(panel);
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1090)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
        at person.guifirst.<init>(guifirst.java:32)
        at person.person.main(person.java:6)
```

Comment: Please format your code, ant tell which is the line 32 on guifirst.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `label1` so this line fails

```
panel.add(label1);
```

You're trying to initialize it in a method that won't get called until the UI is generated and the button is clicked

```
    class addaction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            double number=Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
            double result=number*number;
            label1=new JLabel("Your result is"+result);
        }
    }
```

This won't work because that code won't get executed until an action is performed. The `Component` (the label) needs to be non `null` before it can be added to the `JPanel`.

You need to initialize it to some default value to start with.

Comment: Everything correct but the "asynchronous". This code is called by the event dispatching thread (synchonously) when the button is pressed. So this is what you need to do: create the label for the result already when you create the rest of your GUI and just set its text when the button is pressed.

Comment: @oddparity Aha. I was not aware of how Swing manages events like that, but what I meant was that initialization won't happen synchronously. Changed my wording.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is attempting to add `label1` without instantiating it.

```
panel.add(label1);
```

Remember, variables of an Object type are always references in Java so, even if you instantiate a label1 before making that call, your ActionListener won't replace the label in the frame; it will just change the reference you have to something else, while leaving the old label in the container.

Instead, you should instantiate a label and add it to the component. Then, in your ActionListener, use the `setText(String)` method to change what the label displays.

Comment: No, "private JPanel panel1" is a normal declaration of an instance variable. Sorry for insisting on correct wording.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on [`Container#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29)

> Throws: NullPointerException - if comp is null

It looks like the following line is the culprit

```
panel.add(label1);
```

Since you don't instantiate that variable until you call the `actionPerformed` in your `ActionListener`, it's still `null` when you're trying to add it to `panel`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class guifirst extends JFrame {
     JLabel label;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JTextField text;
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;

    public guifirst() {
        label = new JLabel("Enter a number");
        label1 = new JLabel();
        setSize(450, 100);
        text = new JTextField(15);
        button = new JButton("Calculate");
        class addaction implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                double number = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
                double result = number * number;
                String result_S ="" + result;
                label1.setText(result_S);
            }

        }
        ActionListener listener = new addaction();
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(button);
        add(panel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom of the Exception stack trace tells you where in the code the Exception originated:

```
at person.guifirst.<init>(guifirst.java:32)
at person.person.main(person.java:6)**
```

The above tells you that something in the main method of the "person" class on line 6 tried to create a new object of the "guifirst" class, and something in the constructor ("`<init>`") threw a NullPointerException, on line 32 of the guifirst class.

So: take a look at line 32 of guifirst.java (without line numbers, it's hard to tell which line of your code sample that is). See if you are trying to access a method or property of a reference which could potentially point to null (rather than an instance of an object).

A good rule of thumb when diagnosing NullPointerExceptions is to start by looking for the *periods* (".") in your code, and making sure that whatever is on the **left** side of the period is guaranteed to be a reference to an object.  If that left side can ever be null, then you're setting yourself up for NullPointerException at some point.

By the way, since you're new to Java, it's probably worthwhile to point out that there is a strong established convention in Java coding that type names (i.e. for classes, interfaces, and enums) should begin with a capital letter.  I'd recommend changing the name of your person class to "Person", and "guifirst" to "GuiFirst".